# Why parent task finishes before his children tasks?

Tags: c#

In my code parent task finishes before his children tasks.
Why does it happen?

I thought parent task shouldn't finish before child task finishes.

My code:

```
var parent = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int[] tab = new int[3];

    new Task(() =>
    {
        tab[0] = 9;
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child1");
    }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

    new Task(() =>
    {
        tab[1] = 2;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child2");
    }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

    new Task(() =>
    {
        tab[2] = 3;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child3");
    }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

    Console.WriteLine("I am here");
    return tab;
});

var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith((a) =>
{
    a.Result.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);   
});

finalTask.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Out of threads");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Results:

> I am here
>  9
>  2
>  3
>  Out of threads
>  Child3 Child2
>  Child1

Comment: Did you try to flush the stdout before task exit? The parent task is not finished before its children, but when it finish it flush stdout to console, make it look like the children finish first

Comment: What output are you expecting and why?

Comment: I expected:
I am here<br />
Child3<br />
Child2<br />
Child1<br />
9<br />
2<br />
3<br />
Out of threads<br />
becouse finaltask should wait for parent and parent should wait until his children finishes

Answer (score 2):

I think, I found a reason:
"Parent tasks implicitly prevent child tasks from attaching to them if they are created by calling the `Task.Run` method."
So, I shouldn't use `Task.Run()`, I should use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` instead.

Comment: Does this produce your desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not waiting for the `parent` tasks by calling `parent.Wait();`. See [Attached and Detached Child Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks#attached-child-tasks) for more information. specifically the example shown.

Comment: But finalTask is waiting until parent finishes ("var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith((a) =>{}"), and I added finalTask.Wait();

Answer (score 0):

Though using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` with `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` option is best option to attach child thread with parent. But another way could have been by using 
`Task.WaitAll` in parent thread function. Only advantage is that one can use a `timeout` time with `WaitAll`.

One can re-write block as:

```
var parent = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int[] tab = new int[3];

    var child1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        tab[0] = 9;
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child1");
    });

    var child2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        tab[1] = 2;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child2");
    });

    var child3 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        tab[2] = 3;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Child3");
    });

    Task.WaitAll(child1, child2, child3);  //Wait for all 3 threads to complete. 

    Console.WriteLine("I am here");
    return tab;
});

var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith((a) =>
{
    a.Result.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
});

finalTask.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Out of threads");
Console.ReadLine();
```